# How can I filter by jsonb object value inside array?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a jsonb column called `meta` with this value:

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "baz"
  }
}
```

When I want to filter by the `meta.foo.bar` value, I can do this:

```sql
select * from tbl where meta->foo->>bar = 'baz';
```

Now let's say I want to make the `foo` an array of objects instead:

```json
{
  "foo": [
    { "bar": "baz 1" },
    { "bar": "baz 2" }
  ]
}
```

How can I filter by the `meta.foo.*.bar` values? Tried various combinations of this `->` syntax without any luck. Only thing that worked was searching by a specific index in the array, but I want to check all the items, not just one.

FWIW I'd also like to support multiple nested arrays. The use case is filtering by JSON properties in an ORM (http://mikro-orm.io/), so it needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the `jsonb` containment operator `@>`:

```
SELECT '{"foo": [{"bar": "baz 1"}, {"bar": "baz 2"}]}'::jsonb @>
       '{"foo": [{"bar": "baz 1"}]}'::jsonb;
```

Alternatively, you could use a JSONPATH query:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_exists(
          '{"foo": [{"bar": "baz 1"}, {"bar": "baz 2"}]}',
          '$.foo[*] ? (@.bar == "baz 2")'
       );
```

To search for `bar` no matter how deep it is nested, you can

```
SELECT jsonb_path_exists(
          '{"foo": [{"bar": "baz 1"}, {"bar": "baz 2"}]}',
          '$.**.bar ? (@ == "baz 2")'
       );
```

If you want to search with `= 'baz 2'`, you will habe to unnest the array:

```
SELECT *
FROM jsonb_array_elements(
        '{"foo": [{"bar": "baz 1"}, {"bar": "baz 2"}]}'::jsonb -> 'foo'
     ) AS elem(j)
WHERE j->>'bar' = 'baz 2';
```

But then you have to know exactly where in the JSON you want to search.

Comment: Which is not really what I am looking for, this would mean I have to construct the right hand side. In my context the right hand side is just a string (e.g. `baz 1`), not a JSON.

Comment: I am looking for a generic solution, as I am targetting multiple databases, not just pg. With mysql something like this should be possible: `json_extract(meta, '$.foo[*].bar') = 'baz 1'`, maybe there is a similar way with some function?

Comment: Perhaps a JSONPATH query would make it simpler? Things do become complicated when you use JSON.

Comment: Yeah also saw that way already, but it is quite problematic for me as, again, I'd have to dynamically construct the right hand side, which can be much more complicated, e.g. with operators. I was looking for a way where the right hand side would stay as simple string like `baz 1`.

Comment: Also with this approach, how would nested arrays (of objects) work?

Comment: I have added a few more things you can do, take your pick.

Comment: I do know exactly where in the json I want to search (the path), so the `**` solution also won't work. And for the last one with `jsonb_array_elements` I don't see how it could work with nested arrays (I mean it could probably work, but it feels extremely complicated, how come this is so easy in MySQL :D it's been a while since I saw something done "better" in MySQL). Anyway, thanks a lot for the hints.

Comment: Yes, this is complicated, since you are using JSON. If you know where to search, the first solution is the best. It is simple to construct the JSON from your search string.

Comment: Well, yes, but it would be much more complicated for the use case I have (multidialect ORM), as with other drivers the right hand side would be different. So instead of dealing just with the left hand side, I'd have to introduce new abstractions, which is not worth it for such an edge case.

Comment: You can write a table function if your ORM keeps you from writing SQL.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2:** Based on additional information in the comments, if you want to use other operators (e.g. `LIKE` or `>=`), then you could do something around the following lines:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM jsonb_path_query(meta, '$.foo[*].bar') extracted
  WHERE extracted = '"baz 1"'
);
```

Please note that the filter value must be JSON encoded (therefore the `"` quotes around the string value).

Similar results can be achieved using `JOIN`s or `WITH` CTE's but one must be careful about JOIN-style row duplication.

---

**UPDATE 1:** Thinking about it, you may want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE jsonb_path_query_array(meta, '$.foo[*].bar') ? 'baz 1';
```

---

**My original answer:**

Since Postgres 12 you should be able to use the `@@` jsonpath operator:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE meta @@ '$.foo[*].bar == "baz 1"';
```

Comment: This looks interesting, but I want to be able to use operators, e.g. `like` or `>=`, which is apparently not possible this way

Comment: @MartinAdámek I see, then you may want to extract the data first using `json_path_query` and use `EXISTS`/`JOIN`/`WITH` for filtering. See the updated answer.